# Tailwind min width does not work. Any ideas?

Tags: tailwind-css

Why doesn’t this work?

```
min-w-[40px],
min-h-[40px],
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-width

Comment: maybe it gets override by other styles, did you check css with inspect element?

Comment: Nah, no overrides

Comment: Trivial problems may lie behind it. The first thing that comes to mind is that the code may not have been "compiled" into native CSS. For example, during development, it might not be running "npm run dev," or in the case of a production version, it might not be fetching the latest version with the "npm run build" command, or something similar. This should work unless there is an override. Alternatively, Tailwind might not be installed correctly (assuming no other classes have been used yet).

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Or it's possible that Tailwind is not scanning your file because you omitted it from the configuration file. It could also be the case that these are not fixed values, but rather a variable like 40px. In this scenario, Tailwind won't be able to map anything since it can only insert class names that are explicitly typed. If you want to set the minimum pixel width or height with a variable, simply use native CSS yourself.

Comment: Looks like it works here, I wonder whats going on with my setup https://play.tailwindcss.com/5yqch5Wys0

Comment: hey.. can you share the whole element where you're trying to use this class name?

Answer (score 0):

look in the doc for tailwind down must add custom width in your tailwind.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
   theme: {
       extend: {
          minWidth: {
            '128': '32rem',
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have already created the file with

```
***style.css file in the project root***
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

`tailwindcss -i ./style.css -o ./tailwind.css`

so I have no idea what could be missing, if the other stylings are working it could be a CSS error, or if you are using rust in some cases this [] from tailwind causes problems and you need another config, which I won't post because I don't know what you're using (js next/react or rust/leptos/yew)

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note -

- Make sure that the minWidth property is not purged in your Tailwind CSS configuration file.
   `module.exports = { // other configurations... purge: [], }`
- Make sure that class is not being overridden by other conflicting styles
- if needed, use | to force the style - `min-w-[40px]!`
- Make sure you are not unintentionally applying responsive variants that might override the min-width property on certain screen sizes

`min-w-[40px] sm:min-w-[60px]`

- Use developer tools on chrome to check why and what is happening to that style class and if its conflicting with anything else.

Let me know if this helps.